# dúvida sobre JPQL

Tags: java, jpql

Olá, pessoal. Estou utilizando o JPQL no meu projeto para criar alguns comandos de acesso ao banco de dados e estou com dificuldades para manipular a linguagem. Estou postando o trecho do código com o qual estou tendo dificuldades.

```
public Usuario porNome(String nome) {
    Usuario usuario = null;
    try {
        usuario = this.manager.createQuery(" from Usuario where lower(nome) = :nome", Usuario.class)
                .setParameter("nome",nome.toLowerCase()).getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        // Nenhum usuario encontrado com o nome informado.
    }
    return usuario;
}
```

Neste método, estou recebendo um parâmetro que se chama "nome" e estou procurando na tabela "Usuario" para ver se encontro algum registro com esse nome. Estou utilizando este método para um campo de pesquisa para consultar usuários do meu sistema.

O problema está no fato de que com este código que postei acima, ele retorna somente registros que possuam exatamente o mesmo nome que eu digitar no campo de pesquisa, incluindo os maiúsculos e minúsculos. Por exemplo, se existe um registro no meu banco com o nome "BRUNO DE TAL", eu preciso digitar "BRUNO DE TAL" no campo de pesquisa para que a minha pesquisa encontre este registro. Se eu digitar somente "BRUNO" ou "bruno de tal", ele não encontra o registro.  O que eu quero saber é como eu devo reescrever o meu código JPQL acima e fazer com que ele:

- Ignore a questão de maiúsculos e minúsculos. Por exemplo, se existir um registro com o nome "Bruno" no banco, eu quero que ele seja encontrado tanto quando eu digite "Bruno" como quando eu digite "bruno" no campo de pesquisa.
- Encontre registros do banco digitando somente uma parte do nome. Por exemplo, se existir algum registro do banco com o nome "Bruno de tal", eu quero que este registro seja encontrado quando eu digitar "Bruno" ou "de" ou "tal" no campo de pesquisa.

Eu sou iniciante em JPQL e ainda confundo alguns comandos com o SQL. Por isso gostaria de pedir o conhecimento de vocês.

Agradeço a todos que postarem qualquer resposta ou sugestão.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode resolver a sua necessidade usando o comando LIKE, que também existe no JPQL.

E para resolver o problema do mai/min, basta usar a função lower dos dois lados.

...where lower(nome) LIKE lower(:nome)...

E na hora de setar o nome:

"%" + nome + "%"

Entretanto, existe um possível problema na sua implementação. Se por algum motivo, existir mais de uma pessoa com o mesmo "pedaço de nome", a função singleresult vai retornar uma exceção, pois ela vai encontrar mais de um registro. Neste caso, você deve retornar uma lista.

Comment: Geovane, experimentei implementar do jeito que você falou, mas não deu certo. A questão de retornar somente quando a pesquisa está exatamente igual, incluindo maiúsculos e minúsculos, continua

Comment: Tenta assim: this.manager.createQuery(" from Usuario where lower(nome) LIKE :nome", Usuario.class).setParameter("nome","%" + nome.toLowerCase() + "%").getSingleResult();

Comment: Se existir mais de um usuário com o mesmo "pedaço de nome", vai retornar uma exceção.